# Theirs will be a great torment

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have run into such a verse in Quaran:

> Allah has set a seal on their hearts and on their hearings, and on their eyes there is a covering. *Theirs will be a great torment*

How should I parse the last phrase? What does *theirs*  mean exactly here? Their destiny after death? Their things, so to speak?

Comment: The referent of the ultimate *theirs* in that passage is the same as in the prior one: these people who have seals on their hearts and ears and eyes. The last sentence is saying that not only will these people be tormented, they will be tormented great. The torment which they will have will be a great one. And in he context of scripture it does seem to imply punishment in the afterlife, but that's interpretation; it could also mean they will suffer while they live.

Answer (score 6):

You could rearrange that sentence to:

> A great torment will be theirs.

Since "theirs" means "belonging to them", this in turn can be rephrased as "A great torment will belong to them", or simply "They will receive a great torment".